# {"Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: .net, winforms, sqlite, c#-4.0

I am working on a windows forms application. when I run the application on windows 8 (VS2012), the application runs upto an extent and then crashes, giving the exception "{"Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}".

I am unable to include sqlite3 dll in the references. when I try adding it and change the Copy Local attribute to True, I am unable to do it as whenever I build the solution, this attribute gets changed to False automatically.
also when I try adding SQLite3 through the release\x64 folder, I get an error that the file is not accessible.
kindly help me fix this issue!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the x64 (64 bit) version of sqlite3.dll to the folder that contains your executable file.
Make sure you unblocked the file. You can unblock it by right-clicking on it in the Windows Explorer. In the lower right corner of the General tab you should see an "Unblock" button.

You can't add it as a reference, because it isn't a .NET assembly.

Comment: I tried doing that.. now I am getting the following error: 
"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Comment: @Sid: OK, so the problem is something else. I changed my answer, please check.

Comment: I tried this too.. this is the error I get:
"Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_v2' in DLL 'sqlite3'.":""

Comment: @Sid: This sounds like a versioning mismatch and should be asked as a new question.

Comment: this is the solution to the problem:
I added a dll named SQLite.Tests into my solution and removed Sqlite3.dll from it. It worked well and now I am not getting any exceptions.