# Universal Windows App Using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm getting the following error:

> `Message` = The type initializer for `'SQLitePCL.raw'` threw an exception.
>        `Message` = Unable to load `DLL 'sqlite3'`: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Below is my code:

```
int recCtr = 0;
var root = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbName);
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();
string tempDeckGroup = Global.currentDeckGroup.ToString() + Global.currentDeck.ToString();

using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    var list = db.Table<Decks>().Where(n => n.DeckGroup == tempDeckGroup).ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        recCtr++;
        myCollection.Add(item._id.ToString() + "~" + item.WordName.ToString() + "~" + item.Definition.ToString());
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I run the app using the `Microsoft Phone Emulator.`  The `code executes with no errors` if I deploy to a `Local Machine or Simulator.`

I'm using the `latest SQLite refernces (VSIX) and SQLite-net.pcl`

I don't have a physical device to test on. `(Windows 10 Phone)`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate, but first try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744293/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exceptio%20%22here) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894273/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-except).